# How can I troubleshoot why flask file system session data is lost

Tags: python, flask, flask-session

I have an application (running in Docker and managed by Marathon) where I use server side flask sessions - FileSystemSessionInterface (permanent sessions).

My problem is that if the user waits too long to go to the next step, the session data is lost.

One of my assumptions was that this is because of Marathon, which performs health checks of the application by making an http get request every 2 seconds. This results in a new session file open on every request. And my assumption was that the maximum number of open files is reached. However, when I check in the docker container how many session files are open, the number is not that big, around 350 files.

Did anyone have this problem, any ideas on why my session data disappears?